# How can java application request access to network volume?

Tags: catalina, permission, java, disk-volume

My app is completely written in java (we moved to java11 from java8) and was running fine under High Sierra. 
`new RandomAccessFile(file_on_network_volume, "rws")` gained access and execution continued.

With **Catalina** it fails with 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Volumes/messages/xyz/FILE.xdt (Operation not permitted)`

I understand that any application trying to access a network volume needs a special permission, I reviewed them in System Preferences and they can be removed with `tccutil reset SystemPolicyNetworkVolumes [bundle_id]` for proper testing.

How does the java code properly request the access right from the user so that the processing might continue?

What I did so far:

- changed the code to 
  `AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedExceptionAction<RandomAccessFile>) () -> new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws"));` 
  That caused a JUnitTest run with IntelliJ to request the right by a dialogue
  [image: request user for access to network volume] 
  then the test succeeded to do the required operation on the network volume. 
  The effect is the permission indicated in system preferences as expected: 
  [image]
- added in the Info.plist the entry 
  `<key>NSNetworkVolumesUsageDescription</key> <string>@@bundle_name@@ benötigt Zugriff auf ein Netzwerkvolume.</string>` 
  corresponding to the text in the dialog displayed to the user

But still something's missing. The app **does not** request the permission and consequently the operation fails. IntelliJ does something right that I didn't figure out so far.

Comment: Isn't this technically a programming question and therefore belongs to SO?

Comment: The junit test seems to show that the programming might be done and something very macos specific is missing/gets in the way. But you are right, so far I don't know where the main starting point is. A programming hint is welcome, too.